# Mongo DB track DDL changes

Tags: mongodb, schema, ddl

I am new to Mongo DB.I came from RDBMS/MPP/ETL background and most of the Data stores I used have the metadata about the objects(tables view etc).My doubt is specific to Mongo DB .Does it have any data dictionaries like Oracle user_tables or any other meta information about collections last DDL updated time since MongoDB is a schema less DB, application can change the insert data without schema changes .So finding any structure change before running ETL jobs is important when there is MongoDb involved .I searched for dictionaries or any API information which is tracking the DDL change and found nothing.Can anyone guide me to the links or information related to this.If there is no options like this is there any better best practises to follow to avoid these kind of schema evolution

Thanks
Anoop R

Answer (score 0):

One amongst the advantage of using Mongodb is its schema less structure of storing documents. Now unlike RDBMS table dictionaries, the schema lives in the application layer for MongoDb users. That gives the flexibility to application to design/change schema whenever without waiting on any alter statement dependencies.

Having said that Mongodb 3.2 introduced schema validation and 3.4 enriched it. You can learn more about the validation here [Mongodb document validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/). Validation rules are specified on a per-collection basis using the validator option, which takes a document that specifies the validation rules or expressions.

A point to note about schema validation is not to track the ddl changes but to build an agreed upon definition so to speak.

Comment: I added an answer which you can validate .I am still working on the solution as I am facing some issues with str data type

Comment: @AnoopR You are just sampling for 30docs and determining the type of schema structure. How is it fool proof and if you end up scanning every document, then it will perform poorly with production volume. How can it be better?

Comment: Hi actually for unit testing purpose I gave 30records .In real scenario all the delta data will be considered and it is a time consuming process so mostly will run in a scheduled manner

Comment: Thinking more about this, why does your job care about he fields as long it's not a "select *" type of query. Let the batch job select only the fields that are required for it to be processed. That way you can make use of schema validation and get rid of this scanning.

Comment: Yeah our job normally won't fail unless and until some data type changes .But it's a auditing mechanism to know about the schema evolution and notify respective stake holders

Comment: Data type change is exactly what "schema validation" gives you :) you are just going to kill the cluster with scanning method

Comment: Schema validation is server level thing which we don't have access .For us mongo DB is just one source of data only read only access .So implementing something in DB layer is not possible in current scenario.This job not going to run everyday or for each collections .Its a utility to validate some collections adhoc or on demand

Answer (score -1):

I got a solution which is not actually I am trying for But I think we can manage using that .`

### default checklist for data types

```
key_type_default_count = {
    int: 0,
    float: 0,
    str: 0,
    bool: 0,
    dict: 0,
    list: 0,
    set: 0,
    tuple: 0,
    None: 0,
    object: 0,
    unicode: 0,
    "other": 0,
}
```

### custom code to get the mongo connection

```
client = create_mongo_con(v_env,v_con_name)
print client

db = client[v_db_name]
collection = db[v_collection]
```

### main code

```
key_type_count = defaultdict(lambda: dict(key_type_default_count))


mongo_collection_docs = collection.find({},{"_id":0}).limit(30)
#print mongo_collection_docs'
print type(mongo_collection_docs)

for doc in mongo_collection_docs:

    for key, value in doc.items():
        print ' my key '+str(key)
        print 'my value is '+str(value)
        print ' my value type '
        print type(value)
        if type(value) in key_type_count[key].keys():
            key_type_count[key][type(value)] += 1
        else:
            key_type_count[key]["other"] += 1
    total_docs += 1`
```

You can refer more about this https://github.com/nimeshkverma/mongo_schema from where I got the idea but that code was not working for .I edited some of the part and now I am able to generate a pretty output like this
[image]

But now I am facing one issue with all string fields are detected as unicode.I need to figure this out will post If we got a solution.If anybody faced same issue with str and unicode in python please comment

Comment: This isn't a scalable solution and shouldn't be used for PROD

Comment: I agree with your point .But it is not part of daily jobs and even we can validate collections which is more relevant .So I don't think this will be a problem when you are running on delta data for validation.

Comment: How do you know if its delta data? How can you keep an watermark of what was searched and what wasn't?

Comment: This is not the final code .We need to keep last updated time and filter only records which is greater than last updated date.This is normal ETL world solution and we tried this and worked for our collections.Currently we are not facing any performance issue .As you said for collections with millions of real time data we can't use this method.Anyways for those kind of collections we wont go with a simple python script approach